# Try invoke tkiner.showwarning at a thread when I using python tkiner it's being not responsing

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

When I try invoke `tkinter.show` warning at a thread after doing something if clicked a button, the `gui` will be not responding and the messagebox not show, this is the demo codes, please help:

````
```python
 # coding=utf-8  
from tkMessageBox import *
from Tkinter import *
import thread  
def show_alert(title, msg):
    showwarning(title=title, message=msg)  
def onclick():
    try:
        thread.start_new_thread(show_alert, ("test", "hahahaha!"))
    except Exception as e:
        print "error:", e  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _root = Tk()
    _root.resizable(width='false', height='false')
    _root.title("Test")
    _submitButton = Button(_root, text="submit", width=10, command=onclick)
    _submitButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20)
    _root.mainloop()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is maybe with threading in Python 2 and with some modules - in this case with Tkinter. I don't have very good experience with threading in Python 2. Sometimes in simple cases, it works ok, but when something more difficult, threading in Python 2 with some modules can be unpredictable.
Threading in Python 3 is much more optimized.

So in your case, you have two possibilities.

1) Raise your version to Python 3, namely in these days Python 3.6.

The code in Python 3 is slightly different, but in this case, works like a charm according to your expectations.

```
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter import *
import _thread

def show_alert(title, msg):
    showwarning(title=title, message=msg)

def onclick():
    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(show_alert, ("test", "hahahaha!"))
    except Exception as e:
        print("error:", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _root = Tk()
    _root.resizable(width='false', height='false')
    _root.title("Test")
    _submitButton = Button(_root, text="submit", width=10, command=onclick)
    _submitButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20)
    _root.mainloop()
```

2) If you need to stay with Python 2, try to avoid threading, so you can call `showwarning` directly in `onclick()`

```
from tkMessageBox import *
from Tkinter import *

def onclick():
    try:
        showwarning(title="test", message="hahahaha!")
    except Exception as e:
        print "error:", e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _root = Tk()
    _root.resizable(width='false', height='false')
    _root.title("Test")
    _submitButton = Button(_root, text="submit", width=10, command=onclick)
    _submitButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20)
    _root.mainloop()
```